# Best way to draw on canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

whats the best way of drawing the below image on canvas in such a way that the tail should move independent of its body

[image]

Below is the code which I tried drawing it:

```
RectF rectf = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);                            
path.arcTo(rectf, startAngle, sweepAngle);
path.lineTo(linex, liney);
```

Explanation :

I am drawing a circle inside a rectangle. I am not drawing a complete circle, I am starting from say 0 degree to 350 degree and then I am drawing a line from where the arc stops.

The image is coming perfect. The problem is with rotation, when I try to rotate the entire canvas rotates but I want only the tail to rotate.

For rotating I am using below code:

```
//This line is being called inside onDraw()
canvas.rotate(rotation, (left+right)/2, (top+bottom)/2);
```

I am basically trying to rotate the bubble onTouch event

```
View.OnTouchListener touch = new View.OnTouchListener() {


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();
            updateRotation(x,y);
            invalidate();

        }
        return true;
    }
};


public void updateRotation(float x, float y) {

        double r = Math.atan2(x - (getWidth()/2),  (getHeight()/2) - y);
        rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);

   }
```

My complete onDraw() method is below:

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    path.reset();

    left = 50;
    top = 50;
    right = getWidth()- 50;
    bottom = getHeight()-50;
    startAngle = 100;
    sweepAngle = 335;
    linex = (left + right)/2;
    liney = bottom + 50;

    canvas.rotate(rotation, (left+right)/2, (top+bottom)/2);

    RectF rectf = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
    path.arcTo(rectf, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    path.lineTo(linex, liney);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.restore();

}
```

Image Before rotation:

[image]

Image after rotation:

[image]

Comment: add another image after rotation

Comment: @pskink I have added the images in my question

Comment: so it is a "normal" rotation  with a pivot, whats the problem then?

Comment: as u can see in the image the entire canvas is rotating. I want only its tail (v-shape part) to rotate (the tail should move along the edge of the figure. I hope u understood wat I am trying to achieve)

Comment: out of interest, could you use them as two separate items? bubble is always drawn, and depending on when/where  the user presses you draw the bottom bit?

Comment: use a Path to draw a baloon, then to calculate v-part points use a PathMeasure class

Comment: @RuAware thats quite interesting approach I will keep it as backup plan if I dont succeed in this. Thanks :)

Comment: @pskink can u please give me an example if possible. I am not too good with canvas drawing. oR just provide a link

Comment: @Droider there are no examples of PathMeasure

Comment: @pskink okay if possible could just explain in a bit detail. I just have a feeling that ur approach might just work

Comment: @Droider call getPosTan with different distances, for example 40 and 45 and see "pos" array

Comment: @pskink u could write ans below describing ur approach in a bit detail it will be very helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: @pskink I have no idea whats getPosTan is . But I found a link which is related to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165461/object-following-custom-path I am reading it know and trying to understand wat it is. I still request u to write an ans if possible :)

Comment: I would really help me and others to understand it who are new to android-canvas :)

Comment: @Droider i already answered: call getPosTan twice, with two different distances, fir exanple 40 and 45, whats unvlear in that?

Comment: @pskink As I said I dont knw whats getPosTan() is. And I dnt knw how to use it also

Comment: @Droider http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html#getPosTan(float, float[], float[])

"Pins distance to 0 <= distance <= getLength(), and then computes the corresponding position and
tangent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent way to much time on this, but it will come in useful for my app.

My idea was to set the point and draw around it, so all you have to do is change linex and liney

How else did you get on?

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    Path path = new Path();
    int left = 50;
    int top = 50;
    int right = getWidth()- 50;
    int bottom = getHeight()-50;
    int linex = getWidth()/2;
    int liney = getHeight();
    int openSize = 20;


    RectF rectf = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
    int angle = (int) angle(new Point(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2), new Point(linex,liney)); 

    int startAngle = angle + (openSize/2);
    int sweepAngle = 360 - openSize;

    path.arcTo(rectf, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    path.lineTo(linex, liney);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}

private double angle(Point point1, Point point2) {
    double deltaX = (point1.x - point2.x);
    double deltaY = (point1.y - point2.y);
    double angle =  Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360;
    }

    if (angle > 360) {
        angle -= 360;
    }
    // Compensate for 0
    angle -= 180;
    return angle;
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by "How else did you get on?"

Comment: following ur comment in the above sections and the code - When I touch on the circle depending on wer I touched u want to draw the tail right ?

Comment: I am currently following @pskink suggestion I was able to move the object(tail) around the path. I am trying to improvise it as per my needs. If u r looking for the same feature as me u can refer to this link https://bitbucket.org/TedBeer/spritealongpath/src/d4c1f907ca92a7c8d04afcaeaa95aa779465aeb8/src/net/tedbeer/SceneView.java?at=default

Comment: yeah just change linex and liney on your onTouch, it will then work out that angle and draw around that angle.

I tried using pathmeasure but could not get angle from distance along the path when i found the intersection.

Comment: I ran ur code. pretty close. I will try to complete it and post the complete soln here. Thanks :)

Comment: u can set the linex and liney to event.getX() and event.getY() respectively in ur on touch to change ur tail pos

Comment: I would like to know how did u come up with angle() method I think thats the trick

Comment: It gets the angle between the center point and the end point of the line. then uses that to -half the openSize to start the angle, then the sweeep is 30-the openSize. 

The problem with it is that when in the corners on a wide screen device the angle is slightly higher then the oval (bottom left on my screen is 154 when to look good needs to be around 135, So i would just add in a compensation for these. up down left and right are fine.

But in the ontouch: I would also force the linex or liney to the edge nearest the touch

Comment: okay thanks :) and also y openSize is set to 20? any specific reason?